Vs code bug causing code to not enable correctly
Trying to edit some firmware for a 3d printer to enable different functions to make my 3d printer work with it's new motherboard. The problem I'm having, is when I uncomment a #define, it doesn't enable all the functions underneath that #define. So not all of the code gets highlighted and enabled within the #if to #endif section.
I tried many things like changing the #if to #ifdef. Sometimes when I backspace before the #if which puts it on the line above it's original position, it actives and stays activated when I drop it back down to it's original line, but eventually deactivates on its own.
